# Find earliest date for a unique ID then set separate factor to value

Tags: r, date, if-statement, min

I need to determine the earliest date for each unique ID (n=3127) and assign a specific value to it (30), but if the date is not the earliest for the unique ID, then I need to set the value to another factor's.  Here are the data:

```
Date     ID     Count
1/1/2020     1     -37
1/13/2020     1     12
2/1/2020     1     18
3/4/2020     2     470
3/24/2020     2     20
4/1/2020     2     6
```

Final data frame:

```
1/1/2020     1     30
1/13/2020     1     12
2/1/2020     1     18
3/4/2020     2     30
3/24/2020     2     20
4/1/2020     2     6
```

I had a bit of code that worked initially, but something's gone awry:

```
df$Temp1=c(NA,df$ID[2:nrow(df)-1])
df$Count=ifelse(df$ID==df$Temp1, Records3$Count, NA)
df$Count=ifelse((is.na(df$Count)==TRUE), 30, df$Count)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Cheers, Doug

Comment: The earliest date is 1/1/2020 for ID 1, and I guess you want to change it to 30 for Count. But why is 3/4/2020 also changed

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo...I've revised the OP.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is not clear.  Perhaps, we can group by 'ID' and `replace` the first element with 30

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>%
    arrange(ID, Date) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Count = replace(Count, 1, 30)) %>% 
    ungroup
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  Date          ID Count
#  <date>     <int> <dbl>
#1 2020-01-01     1    30
#2 2020-01-13     1    12
#3 2020-02-01     1    18
#4 2020-03-04     2    30
#5 2020-03-24     2    20
#6 2020-04-01     2     6
```

---

Or using `base R`, `order` the data first by the 'Date' and 'ID', then assign the values in 'Count' based on a logical vector created with `duplicated` to 30

```
df2 <- df1[order(df1$ID, as.Date(df1$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")),]
df2$Count[!duplicated(df1$ID)] <- 30
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("1/1/2020", "1/13/2020", "2/1/2020", 
"3/4/2020", "3/24/2020", "4/1/2020"), ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), Count = c(-37L, 12L, 18L, 470L, 20L, 6L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: akrun, your second proposal did the trick.  Thank you for the short, but sweet, solution.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to `Date` class and for each `ID` change `Count` at earliest `Date` to 30.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Count = replace(Count, which.min(Date), 30))

#  Date          ID Count
#  <date>     <int> <dbl>
#1 2020-01-01     1    30
#2 2020-01-13     1    12
#3 2020-02-01     1    18
#4 2020-03-04     2    30
#5 2020-03-24     2    20
#6 2020-04-01     2     6
```